# Adding double datatype values

Tags: c#

As a newbie in C#.Net programming, I have been trying to do some arithmetic calculations and got stuck with operating the doubles specifically when I want to get the whole number with zero decimals as shown in the code below

```
        double a, b;
        a = 2.0;
        b = 2.0;
        double z = a + b;
        Console.WriteLine(z);
```

Output:4, Instead of 4.0
Any resolution please?

Comment: Use *formatting*: `Console.WriteLine(z.ToString("F1"));`

Comment: There is no problem. The number is 4. The *string* you write to the console though is generated using an implicit format. To change this, just define the format you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way you can control your decimal format:

```
        var a = 2.0;
        var b = 2.0;
        double z = a + b;

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:0.00}", z));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.0000}", z));
```

Output from above:

4.00

4.0000

And one more example:

```
        var a = 2.0;
        var b = 2.2;
        double z = a + b;

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:0.0}", z));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.000}", z));
```

Output from above:

4.2

4.200

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you don't want the outputted value rounded if the double is not an integer (i.e. there are digits to the right of the decimal place), in which case formatting to "N1" for all values of `z` would be inappropriate.

```
if ((z % 1) == 0)
    Console.WriteLine(z.ToString("N1")); // should output "4.0"
else
    Console.WriteLine(z); // should output "4.123456789"
```

Comment: the value is not truncated in that case. It is rounded. But otherwise that is a fair point.

Answer (score 0):

Use a string format to do this:

`Console.WriteLine(z.ToString("N1"));`

N is the format type (numeric) and the 1 means 1 decimal place.

Answer (score -3):

There is no problem. The number is 4. The string you write to the console though is generated using an implicit format. To change this, just define the format you want, eg:

```
Console.WriteLine("This is my number {0:N1"},z);
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(@"This is my number {z:N1}");
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(z.ToString("N1");
```

The section  [Formatting Types in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy(v=vs.110).aspx) in MSDN explains how formatting types to strings works in .NT. Methods like the [Console.WriteLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h(v=vs.110).aspx)  and [String.ToFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx#Starting) allow you to specify a predefined or custom format string that controls how a value is converted to a string